# mark last cell on cheap imitation of excel sheet with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, excel, client-side

I create mini excel sheet in asp.net with table and text box above the table.

When I click on the text box above the table (Fx in excel) I want that the last cell in the table will be marked and when I will leave the big text box I will transfer the last cell id and the content to the server.

I want to imitate the behavior of clicking on the big text in excel in Jquery.

How can I do it? (mark last cell and know the last id of the cell)

Comment: So you are saying you have a table and layered above it (think z-index) you have a similar grid of textareas? And you want to send the content of the textarea that was just edited to the database?

Comment: I have structure exactly like excel, one big text box and below grid with text box in each cell and I want to mark the last cell that was click by the user when the user decide to change the content in the large text box above the grid.

Answer (score 0):

$("table").on("blur", "td textarea"),
     function(e) {
          $("table td.last").removeClass("last"); // remove previous "last"
          $(this).parent("td").addClass("last");  // set the new rd to "last"
     });

// get the last chosen td like this
$("table td.last");